# How to pull only the columns selected in multiple combo boxes when using combo boxes to execute a datasheet query in MS Access

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, combobox

Long time creeper of these forums. I have found many solutions and helpful tips here. 'Twas my lifeline through school and continues be so in the workplace. I have finally encountered an issue where I can find no similar thread to help solve my problem. Thus, I am resorting to posting my problem for the first time.

Suppose I have a datasheet with the following information:

> Location TicketSales CardSales TotalRevenue Date

From this data, I pull information on total revenue and average revenue by month and location. I am designing a form to pull this information in a dynamic way. The idea is to have 5 combo boxes and an execute button:

> Location - (SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM Table)
>
> Variable - (TicketSales, CardSales, TotalRevenue)
>
> Metric - (Average, Sum)
>
> Date From:
>
> Date To:

I have no problem creating a combo box with a drop-down list of all the locations.

For the second combo box, I'm not sure I am creating it correctly. For the "Row Source Type", I select "Field List", and in the "Row Source" I enter "`SELECT TicketSales, CardSales, TotalRevenue FROM Table"`. It seems to work.

At this point, I realize I have an issue. I know how to design queries based on the combo box selection when it is a value within a variable, but not select between columns.

**TL,DR:**

So I try and write a query associated with the execute button simply to pull the data being selected (ie. 1 location and 1 variable).

```
SELECT Location, TicketSales, CardSales, TotalRevenue 
FROM Table
WHERE ((Location)=Forms!Form1!Combo0) AND ((TicketSales)=[Forms]![Form1]![Combo2]) OR ((CardSales)=[Forms]![Form1]![Combo2]) OR ((TotalRevenue)=[Forms]![Form1]![Combo2]));
```

I've troubleshot this several times and just can't seem to get it to work. The above is the last attempt I made. I'm getting an error stating my code is too complicated. I've tried If and Else statements as well. No luck.

If someone could just help me get past this part I will tackle the rest. Any input is appreciated. Thanks!